# Automatically play Multiple video on my site at a certain time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Context: Multiple video on an html page.I have a Multiple video on my html page.
I'd like the one video to appear (and autoplay) daily at 11:00 noon EST and second one 12:00 and so on.
Can this be accomplished with JavaScript and HTML?

Comment: Yes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Comment: Do you want to play a specific video on document load depending on the time? Of course it can be accomplished, either you're using something like https://momentjs.com/ or use the Date() function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is it possible.

Let's assume you have a video element in your DOM that has an id of `myVideoElementID` and style `display: none` by default.

Using this function I wrote:

```
function showElementAndPlayVideo(id) {
    const myElement = document.querySelector("#" + id);
    myElement.style.display = 'block'; // this will make the element visible
    myFunctionToPlayVideo(id); // your implementation which depends on the video player you are using
}

function showElementAtTime(id, hour) {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), hour, 0, 0, 0) - now;
    var timeEnd = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), hour, 59, 59, 0) - now;

    if(now >= time && now < timeEnd) { // show and play right now since it's in the period
        showElementAndPlayVideo(id);
    } else if(time < now) { // show and play later because it's not yet the time
        setTimeout(() => showElementAndPlayVideo(id), now - time);
    }
}
```

You can call `showElementAtTime('myVideoElementID', 11)` on page load. This will make your video element ( previously hidden ) visible in the 11:00:00 - 11:59:59 time period.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two parallel array's. One to house the times that the videos should be played and then another to house the sources of the videos to be played.

I would then check each minute to see if the time is contained in the first array.

```js
// Default time functions in JavaScript return single digit hours/minutes.
var timesToPlayVideos = [
    "8:7",
    "9:30",
    "10:45",
    "11:15",
    "12:0",
    "13:0",
  ],
  videoSources = [
    "https://www.google.com/",
    "https://www.microsoft.com/",
    "https://www.msdn.com/",
    "https://www.stackoverflow.com/",
    "https://www.yahoo.com/",
    "https://www.bing.com/"
  ];

function checkIfTimeForVideo() {
  var currentDateTimeStamp = new Date(),
    currentTimestamp = currentDateTimeStamp.getHours() + ":" + currentDateTimeStamp.getMinutes();

  if (timesToPlayVideos.indexOf(currentTimestamp) > -1) {

    // Your code to play video here. Here is some non working example:
    var arrayIndex = timesToPlayVideos.indexOf(currentTimestamp),
      videoSrcToPlay = videoSources[arrayIndex];

    // iframe used only for example purposes. replace with video tag and use:
    //       video.setAttribute("autoplay", "autoplay");
    var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");
    iframe.setAttribute("src", videoSrcToPlay);

    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  } else {
    // .innerHTML used only for example purposes.
    document.body.innerHTML = "Please return at one of the specified times.";
  }
}

window.setInterval(checkIfTimeForVideo, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use npm cron and a bundler. An example for one video:

```
const cron = require('cron');
const job = new cron.CronJob('00 00 11 * * *',
  () => {
    let video = document.createElement('video');
    Object.assign(video, {src:"/assets/yourvideo.xxx",
        autoplay:true,
        controls:"controls"
    });
    document.body.appendChild(video); 
  },null, true, 'America/New_York'); // <== timezone

job.start();
```

Then create a bundle. For example:

```
browserify cronvideo.js -o public/javascripts/bundle.js
```

https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron